# Populating a Spinner from a static Array

Tags: android, spinner

I have a static array, and i need to populate the spinner from this array but im getting this error.. "Cannot resolve Constructor..." This is my code..

```
protected void onPostExecute(String e) {
            super.onPostExecute(e);
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.docSpinner);
            spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,array));
        }
    }
```

Comment: first use `youActivityName.this` instead of `this` and make sure you `array` is a String array

Comment: Can you share the rest of your `AsyncTask` code? Specifically your instantiation?

Comment: @pavneetSingh it worked! But now when i click the drop down menu, my app crashes! :/

Comment: post the logcat error details

Comment: we need erros details , read this https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: If the app crashes, look for anything saying "Caused by" and read the exception, then search for that

Comment: Okay i found the error and fixed it. Thank u Guys!

Answer (score 1):

The first argument in the [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E)) constructor takes a `Context` argument, but judging from your question you are calling this constructor inside an `AsyncTask`, which (unlike, for example, `Activity`) does not inherit from `Context`.

If your `AsyncTask` is a non-static class nested inside a class which extends any sort of `Activity` e.g `Activity` , `AppCompatActivity` etc , you can use `ActivityName.this`. Otherwise, you will need to find some way to get a `Context` to your `AsyncTask`.